# Формирование подписи для авторизации через ЕСИА с КриптоПро сертификатом

Tags: криптопро, есиа

Настраиваем авторизацию сайта через ЕСИА.

Проблема: После перехода по сформированной ссылке с подписью переходим на страницу авторизации, вводим данные, получаем ошибку "Ошибка авторизации", в адресе страницы есть подробности

```
error_description=ESIA-007005%3A+The+client+is+not+authorized+to+request+an+access+token+using+this+method
```

Имеется машина с докером.

Установлен докер контейнер https://hub.docker.com/r/required/cryptopro

Установлен корневой сертификат, сертификат клиента, стоит пробный ключ для КриптоПро.

Цепочки сертификатов проверены методом копирования (https://www.altlinux.org/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

```
cryptcp -copycert -thumbprint "$thumbprint" -df tt.cer
```

На выходе

```
Certificate chains are checked
```

Для ЕСИА требуется подпись в формате PKCS#7 detached signature в кодировке UTF8, затем кодированная в url safe base64

Погуглив, нашел такой вариант:

```
csptest -sfsign -sign -detached -base64 -add -alg "GOST12_256" -in message -out sig
```

Файл подписывается, проверяю

```
csptest -sfsign -verify -detached -base64 -add -alg "GOST12_256" -in message -signature sig
```

На выходе:

```
Detached Signature was verified OK
```

Вопрос - в чем может быть проблема? Куда копать?

UPD: Есть сервис, который умеет подписывать этим же сертификатом, написан на Java и с его подписью ЕСИА авторизует. Сравнив нашу ссылку и ссылку сервиса - нашли отличия только в строке client_secret, то есть в подписи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вобщем нужную для ЕСИА подпись формирует эта команда:

```
cryptcp -signf -dir "/tmp" -der -strict -cert -detached -thumbprint "$thumbprint" -pin "$pin" "/tmp/message"
```

Предварительно надо положить в файлик /tmp/message нужную строку для подписи. И затем забрать ее из файлика /tmp/message.sgn

```
// php
file_put_contents('/import/message', $content);
```

После работы команды преобразовать подпись в url safe base64 и в итоге получается нужное значение для client_secret

```
// php
$encoded = base64_encode($signature);
$encoded = str_replace(array('+','/','='),array('-','_',''),$encoded);
```

Comment: В итоге, запрос нужно подписывать или он становится подписанным после подписи секретного слова?

Comment: лучше оформлять вопросы комментариями. Вообще запрос считается подписанным, если передается подписанная строка аргументом